# Can you define an enum to represent values explicitly known to your app, but still handle unknown values decoded from the backend?

Tags: swift, enums, codable

#### The Problem

Can you define an enum to represent known values for a property in your model while still allowing for unknown values to be returned from the backend?

Short answer: [Yes you can! The answer is below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61150450/168179)

#### More Context

As part of our app, we have defined a set of feature flags that the app uses to enable/disable certain features depending on a set of criteria. These flags are sent back from the backend as an array of strings.

However, in our app, rather than dealing with the messiness of string constants, we want to define those values as an enum which we mark as `Codable` so the compiler handles the encoding/decoding to the actual enum cases for us automatically.

Here's a typical enum for such scenarios...

```
enum FeatureFlag : String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case allowsTrading
    case allowsFundScreener
    case allowsFundsTransfer
}
```

The wrinkle with this design is it doesn't handle values that may be defined, and returned from the backend in the future.

There are several ways to handle this scenario:

1. Abandon the enum and go to string constants.  This is error prone and breaks containment/scoping since any string can participate in this logic.
2. Stick with an enum as-is and force an update to the app when the backend gets updated passing the buck to deployment.
3. Update the backend to handle versioning to only return values known to that version of the app complicating the logic on the backend to know about the various front-ends, which they shouldn't.
4. The most common, defensively program for unknowns by writing your own encoder/decoder methods for *each class/struct* that uses this enumeration, ignoring any flags not known by the current list of cases.

One through three are maintenance nightmares in their own right.  Yes, four is better, but writing all those custom serializers/deserializers can be pretty time-consuming and error-prone, plus it defeats leveraging the benefits of the compiler being able to automatically do it for you!

But what if there's a number five?  What if you can make the enumeration *itself* gracefully handle unknown values at runtime, while remaining lossless in the process, and without having to resort to optionals?

Well that's the exact solution [I present below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61150450/168179)! Enjoy!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TL:DR - The Solution

For those who just want to see the solution, here it is in its entirety.  This allows you to define an enum with known cases, but which can handle any raw value thrown at it at runtime, and do so in a lossless way for re-encoding purposes.

```
enum FeatureFlag : RawRepresentable, CaseIterable, Codable {

    typealias RawValue = String

    case allowsTrading
    case allowsFundScreener
    case allowsFundsTransfer
    case unknown(RawValue)

    static let allCases: AllCases = [
        .allowsTrading,
        .allowsFundScreener,
        .allowsFundsTransfer
    ]

    init(rawValue: RawValue) {
        self = Self.allCases.first{ $0.rawValue == rawValue }
               ?? .unknown(rawValue)
    }

    var rawValue: RawValue {
        switch self {
            case .allowsTrading       : return "ALLOWS_TRADING"
            case .allowsFundScreener  : return "ALLOWS_FUND_SCREENER"
            case .allowsFundsTransfer : return "ALLOWS_FUNDS_TRANSFER"
            case let .unknown(value)  : return value
        }
    }
}
```

### The Explanation

As mentioned above, our app has a certain set of known feature flags.  At first, one may define them like so.

```
enum FeatureFlag : String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case allowsTrading
    case allowsFundScreener
    case allowsFundsTransfer
}
```

Simple enough.  But again, now any value defined with the type `FeatureFlag` can only handle one of those specific known types.

Now say thanks to a new feature in the backend, a new flag `allowsSavings` is defined and pushed down to your app. Unless you have manually written the decoding logic (or resorted to optionals), the decoder will fail.

But what if the enum can handle unknown cases automatically for you, and do so in a completely transparent way?

It can! The trick is to define one additional case, `unknown` with an associated value of type `RawValue`.  This new case handles all the unknown types handed to it when being decoded or even re-encoded.

Let's start by updating our enum with the new `unknown` case.

```
enum FeatureFlag : String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case allowsTrading
    case allowsFundScreener
    case allowsFundsTransfer
    case unknown(RawValue)
}
```

This of course throws a ton of compiler errors thanks to that new case.  Because of it, both `RawRepresentable` and `CaseIterable` can no longer be automatically synthesized by the compiler, so we have to manually implement them ourselves.  Let's start with...

### Manually Implementing the CaseIterable protocol

This is the easiest of the two steps.  Since this 'version' of our app only knows about the first three cases, we can safely ignore all others.  As such, to satisfy the protocol, we define a static `allCases` property that only specifies those cases we *do* care about.

*Of Note: The property type `AllCases` here is an alias for `[FeatureFlag]` or more succinctly `[Self]`, which we get for free when conforming to `CaseIterable`.*

```
static let allCases: AllCases = [
    .allowsTrading,
    .allowsFundScreener,
    .allowsFundsTransfer
]
```

With the above, this satisfies the `CaseIterable` protocol.  Let's move on to...

### Manually Implementing the RawRepresentable protocol

This is a little more complex/verbose, but this is where the 'magic' happens.

#### Specifying the RawValue type

Normally, to indicate your enum can be represented by a raw value, you specify a data type after an enum's name. In actuality, this is shorthand for telling the compiler you are conforming your enum to the `RawRepresentable` protocol and setting a `RawValue` typealias for that data type.  However, again, because of our `unknown` type having an associated value, the compiler can't do that implicitly, so we must do so explicitly.

To do so, replace your raw type with `RawRepresentable` in the definition, then manually set the `RawValue` typealias inside, like so...

```
enum FeatureFlag : RawRepresentable, CaseIterable, Codable {

    typealias RawValue = String

    case allowsTrading
    case allowsFundScreener
    case allowsFundsTransfer
    case unknown(RawValue)
}
```

#### implementing the rawValue: property (rawValues matching the case names)

Next up, we have to implement the `rawValue` property.  For known cases where the raw value matches the case name, the implementation is simple as we can just return `String(describing: self)` and for the unknown cases, we return the associated value.  Here's that implementation

```
var rawValue: RawValue {

    switch self {
        case let .unknown(value) : return value
        default                  : return String(describing: self)
    }
}
```

#### implementing the rawValue: property (rawValues unrelated to the case names)

But what if we wanted to express different values from the case names, or even a different data type entirely? In that situation, we have to manually expand out the `switch` statement and return the appropriate values like so....

```
var rawValue: RawValue {

    switch self {

        case .allowsTrading       : return "ALLOWS_TRADING"
        case .allowsFundScreener  : return "ALLOWS_FUND_SCREENER"
        case .allowsFundsTransfer : return "ALLOWS_FUNDS_TRANSFER"

        case let .unknown(value)  : return value
    }
}
```

*Note: You must specify the raw values here and not up with the case definitions using the equals (`=`) as that's really syntactic sugar for the compiler to create what we're doing manually here, which again we have to since the compiler can't do it for us.

#### implementing init(rawValue:)... the 'Magic Sauce'

As mentioned, the entire purpose of this exercise is to allow your code to work with known types as usual, but to also gracefully handle unknown cases that are thrown at it.  But how do we achieve that?

The trick is in the initializer, you first search for a known type within `allCases` and if a match is found, you use it. If however a match isn't found, ***rather than return `nil` like in the default implementation, you instead use the newly-defined `unknown` case***, placing the unknown raw value inside.

This has the additional benefit of guaranteeing to *always* return an enum value from the initializer, so we can define it as a non-optional initializer as well (which is different from the implicitly created one from the compiler) making the call-site code easier to use as well.

Here's the implementation of the initializer:

```
init(rawValue: String) {

    self = Self.allCases.first{ $0.rawValue == rawValue }
           ?? .unknown(rawValue)
}
```

In some situations, you may want to log when an unknown value is being passed for debugging purposes.  That can be done with a simple `guard` statement (or an `if` if you prefer) like so...

```
init(rawValue: String) {

    guard let knownCase = Self.allCases.first(where: { $0.rawValue == rawValue }) else {

        print("Unrecognized \(FeatureFlag.self): \(rawValue)")
        self = .unknown(rawValue)
        return
    }

    self = knownCase
}
```

### Interesting Behaviors on Equality and Hashability

One of the interesting things is that enums based on a raw value actually use that value for equality comparisons.  Thanks to that piece of information, all three of these values are equal...

```
let a = FeatureFlag.allowsTrading              // Explicitly setting a known case
let b = FeatureFlag(rawValue: "allowsTrading") // Using the initializer with a raw value from a known case
let c = FeatureFlag.unknown("allowsTrading")   // Explicitly setting the 'unknown' case but with a raw value from a known case

print(a == b) // prints 'true'
print(a == c) // prints 'true'
print(b == c) // prints 'true'
```

Additionally, if your raw value conforms to `Hashable`, you can make the entire enum conform to `Hashable` by simply specifying its conformance to that protocol.

```
extension FeatureFlag : Hashable {}
```

With that conformance, now you can use it in sets or as keys in a dictionary as well, which again, thanks to the rules of equality above, provides for some interesting, but logically expected, behaviors.

Again, using 'a', 'b' and 'c' as defined above, you can use them like so...

```
var items = [FeatureFlag: Int]()

items[a] = 42                     // Set using a known case
print(items[a] ?? 0) // prints 42 // Read using a known case
print(items[b] ?? 0) // prints 42 // Read using the case created from the initializer with a raw value from the known case
print(items[c] ?? 0) // prints 42 // Read using the 'unknown' case but with a raw value from the known case
```

### Side-Benefit: Lossless Encoding/Decoding

One often-overlooked/underappreciated side-benefit of this approach is that serilization/deserialization is lossless and transparent, even for unknown values.  In other words, when your app decodes data containing values you don't know about, the `unknown` case is still capturing and holding them.

This means if you were to then re-encode/re-serialize that data back out again, those unknown values would be re-written identically to how they would be if your app *did* know about them.

***This is incredibly powerful!***

This means for instance if an older version of your app reads in data from a server containing newer, unknown values, even if it has to re-encode that data to push it back out again, the re-encoded data looks exactly the same as if your app *did* know about those values without having to worry about versioning, etc. They're just silently and happily passed back.

### Summary

With the above in place, you can now encode or decode *any* string into this enumeration type, but still have access to the known cases you care about, all without having to write any custom decoding logic in your model types. And when you do 'know' about the new type, simply add the new case as appropriate and you're good to go!

Enjoy!

Comment: I LOVE it! Small thing: change UserFeedback to UserReaction in the example

Comment: Fixed the typo.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Actually, updated it to be `FeatureFlag` since I think more people will understand the concept of 'new values defined after the fact' with that than `UserReactions`.  :)

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much for a so detailed explanation. This is pure gold!

Comment: Glad to help! I was so happy when I figured this out because of how much it simplified our formally-manually decoding process.

Answer (score 2):

Love this proposed [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61150450/5545510)! One small suggestion, add some logging in case the system encounters unknown types.

```
init?(rawValue: String) {
    if let item = Self.allCases.first(where: { $0.rawValue == rawValue }) {
        self = item
    } else {
        self = Self.other(rawValue)
        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            os_log(.error, "Unknown FeatureFlag: %s", rawValue)
        } else {
            print("Error: Unknown FeatureFlag: \(rawValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that!  But it should be 'add logging' because I was thinking when I read 'add error handling' that the entire point is to not throw an error! lol. Great idea tho!

Comment: Ha! True. Changed.

Comment: Lol... I see you changed it back to 'error'.  All good! BTW, I just updated your code to reference `FeatureFlag` since I updated the example as I think more people will follow along with that than `UserReaction`.

Comment: Strange, I didn't change it back (it's now logging again). FeatureFlag sounds good :)